# How to sign some data using public/private RSA key?

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have a RSA public/private key xml file. And I want to use it to sign some data, with the following classes and here is how I use the class:

```
$processor = new RSAProcessor("certificate.xml", RSAKeyType:: XMLFile);
$data =  $processor->sign($data); 
print(base64_encode($data));
```

but I get the error: `WARNING: str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in RSA.php on line 81`. How to fix it? I guess something is outdated for php 7.2? I appreciate your help what changes should I do in my class to avoid this error?

Rsa class:

```
define("BCCOMP_LARGER", 1);
class RSA {
 static function rsa_encrypt($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  $padded = RSA::add_PKCS1_padding($message, true, $keylength / 8);
  $number = RSA::binary_to_number($padded);
  $encrypted = RSA::pow_mod($number, $public_key, $modulus);
  $result = RSA::number_to_binary($encrypted, $keylength / 8);
  return $result;
 }
 static function rsa_decrypt($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  $number = RSA::binary_to_number($message);
  $decrypted = RSA::pow_mod($number, $private_key, $modulus);
  $result = RSA::number_to_binary($decrypted, $keylength / 8);
  return RSA::remove_PKCS1_padding($result, $keylength / 8);
 }
 static function rsa_sign($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  $padded = RSA::add_PKCS1_padding($message, false, $keylength / 8);
  $number = RSA::binary_to_number($padded);
  $signed = RSA::pow_mod($number, $private_key, $modulus);
  $result = RSA::number_to_binary($signed, $keylength / 8);
  return $result;
 }
 static function rsa_verify($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  return RSA::rsa_decrypt($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength);
 }
 static function rsa_kyp_verify($message, $public_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  $number = RSA::binary_to_number($message);
  $decrypted = RSA::pow_mod($number, $public_key, $modulus);
  $result = RSA::number_to_binary($decrypted, $keylength / 8);
  return RSA::remove_KYP_padding($result, $keylength / 8);
 }
 static function pow_mod($p, $q, $r) {
  $factors = array();
  $div = $q;
  $power_of_two = 0;
while(bccomp($div, "0") == BCCOMP_LARGER)  {
   $rem = bcmod($div, 2);
   $div = bcdiv($div, 2);
   if($rem) array_push($factors, $power_of_two);
   $power_of_two++;
  }
  $partial_results = array();
  $part_res = $p;
  $idx = 0;
  foreach($factors as $factor)  {
   while($idx < $factor)
   {
    $part_res = bcpow($part_res, "2");
    $part_res = bcmod($part_res, $r);
    $idx++;
   }
   array_push($partial_results, $part_res);
  }
  $result = "1";
  foreach($partial_results as $part_res)
  {
   $result = bcmul($result, $part_res);
   $result = bcmod($result, $r);
  }
  return $result;
 }
 static  function add_PKCS1_padding($data, $isPublicKey, $blocksize)
 {
  $pad_length = $blocksize - 3 - strlen($data);
  if($isPublicKey)
  {
   $block_type = "\x02";
   $padding = "";
   for($i = 0; $i < $pad_length; $i++)
   {
    $rnd = mt_rand(1, 255);
    $padding .= chr($rnd);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $block_type = "\x01";
   $padding = str_repeat("\xFF", $pad_length);
  }
  return "\x00" . $block_type . $padding . "\x00" . $data;
 }
  static function remove_PKCS1_padding($data, $blocksize)
 {
  assert(strlen($data) == $blocksize);
  $data = substr($data, 1);
  if($data{0} == '\0')
  die("Block type 0 not implemented.");
  assert(($data{0} == "\x01") || ($data{0} == "\x02"));
  $offset = strpos($data, "\0", 1);
  return substr($data, $offset + 1);
 }
  static function remove_KYP_padding($data, $blocksize)
 {
  assert(strlen($data) == $blocksize);
  $offset = strpos($data, "\0");
  return substr($data, 0, $offset);
 }
 static function binary_to_number($data)
 {
  $base = "256";
  $radix = "1";
  $result = "0";
  for($i = strlen($data) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
  {
   $digit = ord($data{$i});
   $part_res = bcmul($digit, $radix);
   $result = bcadd($result, $part_res);
   $radix = bcmul($radix, $base);
  }
  return $result;
  }
 static  function number_to_binary($number, $blocksize)
 {
  $base = "256";
  $result = "";
  $div = $number;
  while($div > 0)
  {
   $mod = bcmod($div, $base);
   $div = bcdiv($div, $base);
   $result = chr($mod) . $result;
  }
  return str_pad($result, $blocksize, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
 }
}
```

RSAProcessor class:

```
class RSAProcessor
{
 private $public_key = null;
 private $private_key = null;
 private $modulus = null;
 private $key_length = "1024";
 public function __construct($xmlRsakey=null,$type=null)
 {
         $xmlObj = null;
         if ($xmlRsakey==null) {
             $xmlObj = simplexml_load_file("xmlfile/RSAKey.xml");
          } elseif ($type==RSAKeyType::XMLFile) {
             $xmlObj = simplexml_load_file($xmlRsakey);
          } else {
             $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlRsakey);
          }
         $this->modulus = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->Modulus));
         $this->public_key = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->Exponent));
         $this->private_key = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->D));
         $this->key_length = strlen(base64_decode($xmlObj->Modulus))*8;
 }
 public function getPublicKey() {
  return $this->public_key;
 }
 public function getPrivateKey() {
  return $this->private_key;
 }
 public function getKeyLength() {
  return $this->key_length;
 }
 public function getModulus() {
  return $this->modulus;
 }
 public function encrypt($data) {
  return base64_encode(RSA::rsa_encrypt($data,$this->public_key,$this->modulus,$this->key_length));
 }
  public function dencrypt($data) {
  return RSA::rsa_decrypt($data,$this->private_key,$this->modulus,$this->key_length);
 }
  public function sign($data) {
  return RSA::rsa_sign($data,$this->private_key,$this->modulus,$this->key_length);
 }
  public function verify($data) {
  return RSA::rsa_verify($data,$this->public_key,$this->modulus,$this->key_length);
 }
}


class RSAKeyType{
 const XMLFile = 0;
 const XMLString = 1;
}
```

certificate.xml:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>tCZiqDS5BVQQZDBUYbyeoP4rENN4mX5FZJjjMNfGbyzfzH45RY2/YsMaY0yI1jMCOpukvkUyl153tcn0LXhMCDdsEhhZPoKbPUGMniKtFGjs18rv/b5FFUUW1utgwoL8+WJqjOqhQGgvbja63X9+WMFP0nM3d8yudn9C/X55KyM=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>5HXvmU4IfqUG2jFLSqi/BMEQ3x1NsUDvx3zN5O1p9yLLspJ4sqAt4RUkxzcGodYgBSdXsR9IGcPwjQfbx3a7nQ==</P>
    <Q>yd2hDCF/5Zqtz9DXjY1NRYGvBjTS4AQn83ERR46Y5eBSnLjpVjv6gPfARuhsUP44nikrQPvwPnjxQcOhJaOlvw==</Q>
    <DP>ztuqUplBP8qU5cN0dOlN7DQT3rFdw30Unv/2Pa5qIAc1gT72YmZ+pCrM3kSIkMicvY3d7NZyJkIv8MKI0ZZEUQ==</DP>
    <DQ>QFLJ5YarLWubZPQEK4vSCornTY/5ff51CIKH4ghTOjS/vkbBu4PDL+NCNpYLJcfMHMG7kap2BEIfhjgjGk5KGw==</DQ>
    <InverseQ>WE6TqpcexQJwt9Mnp1FbeLtarBcFkXVdBauouFKHcbHCfQjA3IjUrGTxgSO74O/4QSKqaF2gnlL6GI7gKuGbzQ==</InverseQ>  <D>czYtWDfHsFGv3fNOs+cGaB3E+xDTiw7HYGuquJz2qjk/s69x/zqFEKuIH8Ndq+eZYFQUCx+EGGxxENDkmYPa0z8wbfFI6JEHpxaLmQfpkkbSL1BJIp9Z5BNM2gy6jJqgbWwQPcN/4jpiMefHZWAqhMKqenUu1KIq1ZX6Bz5xKYk=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I appreciate your help what changes should I do in my class to avoid this error?

Comment: Just wondering, Why do you implement your code while there is an OpenSLL for PHP? and what is the magic number 81 for the readers?

Comment: I am not wondering with openssl, can you please provice the equivalent code for openssl to sign data with this key? And line 81 in that class file is `$padding = str_repeat("\xFF", $pad_length);`

Comment: I guess as my private/public key format is something particular and not a strandard RSA file format, I cannot use openssl and I should fix this code only?

Comment: RSA is an algorithm. There is PKCS#1 which is the common standard for RSA. That defines RSA private key structure using ASN.1, which is commonly DER encoded (there is an XML formatting too called XER, but it is hardly supported anywhere and above is not XER). Usually private keys are stored using PKCS#8 (inner) format, which then includes the key as defined in PKCS#1. Usually that kind of functionality is provided by good crypto libraries (OpenSSL certainly supports it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my local environment, the code runs smoothly, and also on http://phpfiddle.org/ (PHP 7.0.33)! For the latter, however, the key must be passed as string, because online no filesystem is available:

```
$privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue>...</RSAKeyValue>";
$processor = new RSAProcessor($privateKey, RSAKeyType::XMLString);
```

On the other hand, the same code fails on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ (PHP 7.01 - PHP 7.3.5) with the same error message as yours. The reason is that the method `simplexml_load_string()` is disabled. Thus the key cannot be loaded and the member variables `$modulus`, `$key_length`, `$private_key` and `$public_key` of the `RSAProcessor`-class get the value `0`. As a result the method `add_PKCS1_padding`, called with `$blocksize=$keylength/8`, determines a negative value for `$pad_length=$blocksize-3-strlen($data)`, which transparently leads to the error message *str_repeat(): Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0* when `str_repeat("\xFF", $pad_length)` is called.

If I disable the method `simplexml_load_file` in my local environment, I can reproduce exactly this behavior. Since the code works in principle, it can be assumed that methods are disabled on your system as well, especially `simplexml_load_file`.

Disabled methods can be enabled by removing them from the `disable_functions`-list in the `php.ini`.

**Update:**

As already mentioned in the comments, RSA is supported by the vast majority of libraries, e.g. `phpseclib`, [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#sign,xml,xmlpub,sign2,enc1,1.0,), which also supports the key format used in your code, [here](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#create,xml,xmlpub,sign2,enc1,1.0,).

In general for PKCS#1, not the data itself, but their hashes with preceding digest info (DER encoding of the `DigestInfo` value) are signed according to [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2.1), see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#Method), which is why a digest must also be specified. Assuming that your data (i.e. `$data` which is passed to your `RSAProcessor#sign`-method) follow this convention, i.e.:

```
$dataToSign = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'; 
$data = hex2bin('3031300d060960864801650304020105000420' . hash('SHA256', $dataToSign, false));
```

the following code using the phpseclib-library (with SHA256 as digest) would generate the *same* signature:

```
include('RSA.php');
include('BigInteger.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue>...</RSAKeyValue>";
$dataToSign = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);  // private key format
$rsa->loadKey($privateKey);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');                                  // digest for signing
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);        // RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5-padding
$signature = $rsa->sign($dataToSign);

echo 'Signature (hex):    ' . bin2hex($signature) . "\n";
echo 'Signature (base64): ' . base64_encode($signature) . "\n";
```

Both codes then provide the following signature (as hex string):

```
6f00eb1126470e097991aaa1e3e94b49a7b8de6c9b2bf683382f96563479b87067be20635ccc1d36fedff9d60f682fdefcb108f5351dc672ebb442e49231d0306b302b258f6b21fb724b59ad765151f6c724de214d41afa0e1b08228b070c537020df8acf9cad5f2fdde63bc698875527a52e49155bd5e2fd761f541844e92bb
```

**Update 2:**

For SHA1, the ID plus hash for your code can be determined as follows:

```
$data = hex2bin('3021300906052b0e03021a05000414' . hash('SHA1', $dataToSign, false));
```

or

```
$data = hex2bin('3021300906052b0e03021a05000414' . SHA1($dataToSign, false));
```

Either the [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)-function or the [`sha1`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)-function can be used. In both cases, the last parameter `$raw_output` controls whether the return is a binary (`TRUE`) or a hex string (`FALSE`). Because of the concatenation with the ID I return the hash as hex string, do the concatenation and finally convert explicitly with [`hex2bin`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) into the binary representation. The digest ID can also be found [here, page 47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2).

In the phpseclib-code

```
$rsa->setHash('sha1');
```

must be used.

Comment: Both my code and the phpseclib code you gave above gives the exact same result? This is important to get the exact same result because this is for my local bank.

Comment: I guess this sha256, will not give the exact same result as my code? Can you give a phpseclib code that gives the exact same result as mine that I can migrate to phpseclib safely?

Comment: It depends on the content of `$data`: Usually not the data itself are signed, but the hash (including the digest info, see my modified answer) using a given digest. The phpseclib-library does this implicitly, i.e. the data are hashed and the digest info is prefixed, which is why a digest has to be specified. The signatures match if `$data` in your code contains exactly these data (digest info plus hash).

Comment: Yes, my bank is using sha1 with second argument as true to generate 20 length binary hash. So for setHash I have to use sha1, but how to set its second argument as true here?

Comment: If I understood correctly, digest and methods to sign is not important whatever use, as this cannot be decoded. Whatever method you use, the receiver can use public key to verify if this is done by you or not? And this is the purpose of signing? Right?

Comment: Regarding the second-last question, see my modified answer. Regarding the last question: The methods for signing and verifying methods must match, i.e. the same algorithm, the same digest and the same padding must be used (and, of course, a pair of matching keys). For this reason it makes sense to use standards and avoid custom implementations, because even the slightest deviation in the implementation usually leads to a signature and /or verification failure. For the purpose of the digital signature see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

Comment: what is `3031300d060960864801650304020105000420` you concatenate? could you please give the exact equivalent of my code with phpseclib?

Comment: Your code (using SHA1 if I understood it correctly) and the phpseclib-code will *only* return the same result *under the conditions described in Update 2*.
phpseclib implements PKCS#1 according to RFC 8017. For your code to be compatible with PKCS#1, *$data needs to concatenate the SHA1-ID and the SHA-1 hash*. Otherwise, it's not compatible with PKCS#1 and a signature that was created with your code can only be verified with your code and *not* with phpseclib which implements PKCS#1. 3031300d060960864801650304020105000420 is the ID for SHA256 (for SHA1 it is 3021300906052b0e03021a05000414).